# Back button appears with button outline

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am working on an app which supports iOS 6 to latest iOS versions. When I run the app in Xcode 5 and select target as iOS7; Sometimes the back button in navigation bar appears with the iOS6 button style as an outline around it in iOS7. I wanted to enable default feature of iOS7 that back button without outline.

other buttons look fine with iOS7 without outline.

Comment: You will be using a custom button with Image. Pls check it

Comment: Could you supply an image????

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using images for the button, use default system buttons.

Comment: Thanks Nilesh . Yes I was using custom button.

Comment: @user3317914: Ohh, glad i helped, Do you mind accepting the answer..:)

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have used button style as  UIBarButtonItemStylePlain